# How to reference service in another docker-compose.yml in .env?

Tags: laravel, docker

I have some containers on the same network, but they are in separate docker-compose.yml files.

`service_1` is an API container.
`service_2` is a Laravel app using Laradock.

I do this inside both my `docker-compose.yml` files;

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_network
```

I check with `docker network inspect my_network` that both my containers are connected.

Now inside `service_2` in my Laravel env file, i want to reference my_network and grab the ip/host of `service_1` dynamically so I don't have to change the IP everytime.

This doesn't work however, since when I try and make call from my Laravel app it doesn't swap the url and tries to make request to `service_1:443`.

Hopefully someone can explain!

Comment: You should just be able to use `service_1` as a host name, the same way as if the two containers were in the same Compose file; you don't need to manually look up the IP address.  When you say "it doesn't swap the URL" can you describe what's happening in more detail?

Comment: @DavidMaze Both containers will be running, and from my host I can access both, but if I set API_HOST as `service_1` and then make API request to it from `service_2` Laravel, it takes it literally and tries to request `"service_1":443`. In other words it doesn't do the substitution to the hostname properly.

Comment: On a user defined bridge network , it should be possible for containers to resolve container name to ip address. Please see [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#:~:text=On%20user%2Ddefined%20networks%20like%20alpine%2Dnet%2C%20containers%20can%20not%20only%20communicate%20by%20IP%20address%2C%20but%20can%20also%20resolve%20a%20container%20name%20to%20an%20IP%20address) for an example. Probably service_1 is running on a different port. Try removing port from your config as well and let it call service_1 instead which should auto resolve.

Comment: @Nish26 Only port change I made was my nginx host port to 8081 because my REST API is already hosted on 8080. So not sure if that's it?

Comment: nginx should be your reverse proxy .. you can run 'docker ps' command to see ports used by your container after starting them.  you should see something like 80/tcp or 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp (if mapped) for container.

Comment: @Nish26 yes i do and like i said i can already access it from my host. I ran `docker network inspect my_network` and I can see all of the containers connected to it, so I'm still baffled as to why the .env variable isn't being swapped? Should I be using the service name, or the container name?

Comment: Use container name visible from docker ps command. Alternatively you can explore docker network aliases.

Comment: @Nish26 Well those are what I've been using and still no luck, so I don't know anymore. :( Guess I'm just gonna give up since I've wasted about 2-3 days on this at this point and I'm no close to really fixing it.